# Écrit-on l'« espace » ou l' « espace » ?

Tags: orthographe, typographie

Faut-il mettre une espace entre l'apostrophe et le guillemet ?

`l'« espace »` vs `l' « espace »`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il n'y a jamais d'espace avant ou après une apostrophe, quel que soit ce qui se trouve après l'apostrophe. Il faut une espace **après** les guillemets ouvrants et **avant** les guillemets fermants. Donc l'« espace ».

> le trait d'union et l'apostrophe ne sont pas des signes de ponctuation, ne jamais mettre d'espace. [→](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-115768.php)

> Le code typographique précise qu’« il n’y a pas d’espace entre l’apostrophe et le guillemet ouvrant ». [→](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/22039/la-typographie/espacement/espacement-avant-et-apres-les-signes-de-ponctuation-et-les-symboles)

Comment: J'ai posé cette question car j'ai trouvé [cet article](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/elision-et-guillemets/) dans lequel quelqu'un donne des contre-exemples de cette règle.

Answer (score 0):

Une règle valable en Français est le nombre d'éléments pour savoir s'il y a un espace ou non. Si le signe de ponctuation ne comporte qu'un seul élément tels qu'une virgule ou un point,, alors il n'y a pas d'espace. En revanche, s'il comporte deux éléments tels qu'un point-virgule ou un point d'interrogation, alors il y a un espace.

Comment: L'apostrophe n'est pas un signe de ponctuation (c'est un signe orthographique).

Comment: Merci pour l'information !